# What is this plant with purple daisy-like flowers and what hardiness zones will it grow in?

Tags: identification

What kind of plant is this and how hardy is it? Can it be planted outside and if so in what zones?

Plant is as seen in attached photo. Do not have any further information. Would also like to be advised about watering? Light and location? Plant indoors or out?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The leaves look like from the Cineraria genus and with these flowers it looks like a Pericallis x hybrida 'Senetti Deep Blue'

I don't know the plant, but look at next two links for more info;

http://www.armstronggarden.com/senetti-deep-blue.html
http://www.gardenharvestsupply.com/productcart/pc/senetti-deep-blue-pericallis-plant-p5205.htm

Answer (score 3):

If you followed Laurens link, you'll have found out a bit. I have this at the moment in my sitting room - its frost sensitive, but can be placed outside when risk of frost is past. Don't expect it to survive long though - these plants are purely temporary visitors, and you'll be lucky to get a second flowering out of them, despite what the sales blurb says. You can certainly give it a try though, by cutting down and feeding, see if it works.